# How do I include spaces in a grep pattern executed through ssh and dockercli

Tags: ssh, grep, docker

I would like to grep a log file on a remote server using a pattern with spaces, eg.

```
grep 'words with spaces' log.txt
```

The tricky part is that I'm executing a remote dockcli command over ssh.  Something like:

```
ssh hostname "dockercli exec -u username dockername grep 'sentence with spaces' logs/filename.log"
```

When the container executes the grep command, the extra quotes are stripped.  I have tried escaping the quotes (command never returns), reversing order (' before ") and \s.

**How do I include spaces in a grep pattern executed through ssh and dockercli?**

Comment: I don't find "dockercli" in the documentation.  Is it possible to just use "docker exec [OPTIONS] CONTAINER COMMAND [ARG...]"

Answer (score 1):

I dont have `dockercli` but perhaps some experiments using `sh -c` as a replacement may provide a similar command that is parsing the data.

To check that `grep` is being passed the right string I will use the example

```
echo 'a   b' | ssh localhost "grep 'a   b'"
```

This matches the input string which has 3 spaces. If we add an extra `sh -c` layer, we need

```
echo 'a   b' | ssh localhost "sh -c 'grep \"a   b\"'"
```

and again for

```
echo 'a   b' | ssh localhost "sh -c 'sh -c \"grep   \\\"a   b\\\"\"'"
```